# Office 365 SMTP starts firing net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, office365

A while ago I've configured my ASP.NET C# project to send e-mail via Office 365, but last week it's starting to throw a lot of exceptions.

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed. 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 read, Boolean readLine) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader caller, Boolean oneLine) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader caller) 
at System.Net.Mail.CheckCommand.Send(SmtpConnection conn, String& response) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, Boolean allowUnicode, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception) 
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

```
  MailMessage message = new MailMessage(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpfrom"], email, strOnderwerp, strBody);
            message.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpserver"], Convert.ToInt32((System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"])));

            client.EnableSsl = Boolean.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpssl"]); ;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpuser"], System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtppass"]);

            client.Send(message);
            client.Dispose();
```

The exceptions seems to be thrown on the **Dispose**.

Comment: Not pertinent to your question, but I would get those calls to `ConfigurationManager` out of your email sending code. I would write a generic method for sending emails (ex name: `SendEmail`), and pass those values as variables. Put the calls to `ConfigurationManager` in whichever method calls `SendEmail`. Well ... actually I'd wrap my `ConfigurationManager` calls in a normalized class specific to returning Config values, so I can code it like variable `MyAppConfigClass.SmtpServer`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This same issue started at my company on February 8th. The problem would come and go with no pattern.

What I believe solved the problem was a change to the SMTP server address.

Our original SMTP server address was podxxxxx.outlook.com and still works most of the time. I checked for the current O365 SMTP server address in our portal and it should be smtp.office365.com.

I changed my config to point to this new address and the problem seems to have gone away. My logs show no errors for the last 24+ hours after the change.

If the error starts happening again I will update this.

Comment: Replaced pod51014.outlook.com by smtp.office365.com - hoping for the best.

Answer (score 13):

In our case, we were already using `smtp.office365.com` endpoint, yet all of a sudden we started receiving `net_io_connectionclosed` on one of our machines, while same code was working perfectly on others. Investigation shown that those machines resolved `smtp.office365.com` to different IP addresses, and it looked like one of the servers was misbehaving.

On attemt to write support inquiry, it appeared that Microsoft is playing bad trick on us:

> Recently, we started rejecting a percentage of connections to
> smtp.office365.com that uses TLS1.0/1.1 for SMTP AUTH (complete
> disablement will start early 2022).

And that was just it. [Switching to TLS 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751179/tls-1-2-not-negotiated-in-net-4-7-without-explicit-servicepointmanager-security) fixed whole thing.

Comment: It's called a "speedbump", and, apparently, Microsoft *does* [return a useful error message](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/new-opt-in-endpoint-available-for-smtp-auth-clients-still/ba-p/2659652): `421 4.7.66 TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are not supported. Please upgrade/update your client to support TLS 1.2. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_tls.` It's just that the (old) .NET SmtpClient class throws away this information and shows the (useless) generic `net_io_connectionclosed` message instead.

Comment: Yes I had to update the SMTP address to `smtp-legacy.office365.com` and enable legacy TLS clients in the Exchange Admin Center -> Settings -> Mail flow 'Turn on use of legacy TLS clients.'
[Opt in to the Exchange Online endpoint for legacy TLS clients using SMTP AUTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/opt-in-exchange-online-endpoint-for-legacy-tls-using-smtp-auth)

Answer (score 8):

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

this worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

If you all face this issue in 2022, that might be the case of Microsoft decided to stop supporting TLS1.0, TLS1.1 for service endpoint "smtp.office365.com".

To resolve it,
Either use "smtp-legacy.office365.com"
or
Configure client to use TLS1.2 by

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Read [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/new-opt-in-endpoint-available-for-smtp-auth-clients-still/ba-p/2659652) article from Microsoft Tech Community for more details

Answer (score 0):

The holy grail of all this bothering with the net_io_connectionclosed Errors while connecting to Office365 in VB.NET or c# is the TSL Version.

When you are working with a VB.NET oder c# Application wanting to connect, send an receive Msg. to/from O365 you have to force TLS12 in you code.

Just put the last line below your EnableSSL = True an you will be fine:

[Last Line to force TLS12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WNtB.png)