# .net 4.7 fails to create SSL channel when server responds with TLS 1.1

Tags: c#, ssl, https, .net-4.6.2, .net-4.7

I'm trying to do HTTPS GET request using client certificate authentication and it fails with

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I'm trying same request using Java and it works fine, I see following in Java logs (stripped to only interesting parts):

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 185

....

*** ServerHello, TLSv1.1
main, READ: TLSv1.1 Handshake, length = 3339
```

Which as I understand means, that server for some reason does not support TLS 1.2, but client is accepting that and simply fall backs to TLS 1.1.

When I set

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

.NET works fine too. 
Now the question - why .NET does not fall back to TLS 1.1 as Java did, can I enable that fallback somehow (without actually trying TLS 1.2, catch exception and try with TLS 1.1)?

Comment: set SecurityProtocol to SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 ?

Comment: What is the Windows version installed on the machine you run this code on by the way?

Comment: Windows 10 15063.608

Comment: Very interesting, had no idea SecurityProtocolType is marked as Flags! And setting value to SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 works, by default it was SSL3 | Tls. If you would convert comment to answer, I would mark it as confirmed ;)

Comment: Also, interestingly enough, project is .net 4.7 and according to here it behaves as .net 4.5: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/

Comment: Still not very clear for me why you have `Ssl3 | Tls` as default. In .NET 4.7 you should have it as `SystemDefault` by default. Is it completely clean project without any related changes? What if you just create new project and see what default is?

Comment: I've tried creating new 4.7 .net console app and by default it still was Ssl3 | Tls, when I added <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto=false"/> it has changed to Tls | Tls11 | Tls12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In description of [ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol(v=vs.110).aspx) it is stated

> Note that no default value is listed for this property, on purpose.
> The security landscape changes constantly, and default protocols and
> protection levels are changed over time in order to avoid known
> weaknesses. Defaults will vary depending on individual machine
> configuration, and on which software is installed, and on which
> patches have been applied.
>
> Your code should never implicitly depend on
> using a particular protection level, or on the assumption that a given
> security level is used by default. If your app depends on the use of a
> particular security level, you must explicitly specify that level and
> then check to be sure that it is actually in use on the established
> connection. Further, your code should be designed to be robust in the
> face of changes to which protocols are supported, as such changes are
> often made with little advance notice in order to mitigate emerging
> threats.

While on .NET 4.7 the default value of this property should be `SystemDefault` ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net47/dotnet47-changes.md#networking)) and `SystemDefault` means "ask OS about list of default protocols" (and on Windows 10 TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are [enabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt808159(v=vs.85).aspx)) - this value still can be affected by multiple external sources (such as registry keys and as you see above even by installed software or applied patches). As we figuted out in comments, for some reason you have it as `Ssl3 | Tls` by default, which is bad, because `Ssl3` is not even secure and should be disabled.

So to solve your issue (and in future such cases) - always list protocols you need, especially if you publish your applicaiton on multiple client machines, because default setting is not reliable:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Also it looks like same issue on Windows 10 with .net 4.7 is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44751179/tls-1-2-not-negotiated-in-net-4-7-without-explicit-servicepointmanager-security/44765698#44765698

Comment: @Giedrius indeed. But this seems to be not consistent. For example I have the same Windows version as you, but I have SystemDefault by default on .NET 4.7