# Unable to read data from the transport connection VB6 calling com visible c# library

Tags: com, vb6

I have a c# Framework 4.7.2 Com visible library that calls a web api.

Unit tests in the  VS2017 C# IDE library work fine.

However if I try to call via VB6 I get

> System.IO.IOException unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the rempte
>   host.
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

I am running Windows 10

I call as administrator

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /verbose  /tlb:SBD.ComBridge.tlb C:\dev\SBD.ComBridge.dll
```

to create the .dll and .tlb

I also tried running regasm from the VS2017 command prompt as administrator

RegAsm reports that the libraries register successfully.

In Vb6 the (simplified) code is

```
Dim o As SBD_ComBridge.BridgeImplementation
Set o = New dBridgeImplementation
o.SetOrderDates id 
set o = nothing
```

In BridgeImplementation the (simplified) code is

```
[DispId(25)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public void SetOrderDates(int Id)
{
     PackAndSend.SetReadByInfo(Id) // calls freight service
}
```

I know that the code calling the service from within SetReadyByInfo works because my unit test passes when I run it in VS2017

Unfortunately I have been asked not to post the code. However I know that the vb6 code calls Com correctly because there are other methods I call without errors.

I had a similar issue [with MYOB api and TLS](https://apisupport.myob.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000475935-TLS1-0-No-longer-supported) the solution was to upgrade the Framework.  However I can't upgrade the VB6 framework ( the large re-write is not an option)  Probably I will just make a .Exe and shell out to it.

[Update]

The [link Simon Mourier gave me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669060/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-vb6-calling-com-visible-c-shar) solves it.
If I add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

then my com call works on VB6

As the link points out,

> This isn't a good solution since it hard codes what TLS version to
>   use, so it wouldn't use TLS 1.3 in future

Comment: Going to have to show some code, both the calling VB6 code and probably the .NET side too.

Comment: Is `PackAndSend.SetReadByInfo` a blocking call?  It is a .NET exception so I think the next set of code to post is that.

Comment: If you are getting a .NET exception then your VB6 code *did* call the .NET library.  If there is any question on whether or not your VB6 code is loading and calling your .NET library, create a no-op method in the .NET library and call that first.  If that succeeds then we know your are doing basic .NET / COM interop correctly.  Then we can look at `PackAndSend.SetReadByInfo`.  I understand you called it from a unit test, but I bet your unit test is not getting called from an STA threaded 32-bit application to simulate a VB6 program.  One step at a time though.

Comment: If you know the VB6 is calling into the C# `SetOrderDates` correctly, and that code only calls `PackAndSend.SetReadByInfo(Id)`, then the logical next step is to list the source code of that method.  The goal is to review all source code called to see what there might take issue with being called from a VB6 process.  Also, please post the full stack trace of your exception, that would be extremely informative.

Comment: Thanks @tcarvin I updated the question to explain I can't do this and deleted some of my chat comments.

Comment: As you found out, TLS is probably the issue. But you shouldn't have to upgrade anything if the machine and the installed .NET framework support TLS 1.2 (which seems to be the case since you say it works with other programs)
Your VB6 exe is probably not using the good .NET Framework (there can be more than one installed on a given machine), or not using the configuration that works.
Check out the answers here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765698/403671 (adapt to your context)

Comment: Based on @SimonMourier links, you could probably just use code to explicitly set ` ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` as desired.  You could try the config file route, but since VB6 is the host app, I'm not sure a config-file based approach will work.

Comment: @SimonMourier many thanks!

Comment: Thanks :-) If you found the solution, you should answer yourself with some details of what you did to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

As per the update section at the bottom of my question, a work around is to include

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I need to investigate further for a more complete solution